# Save only file names in Windows directory to a CSV with Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I can print directory contents (Windows 10) with Mode, LastWriteTime etc included but I want to use something like `dir > test.csv` to only print the Name of each file. Is there such a way to do this?

Comment: `(Ls "$Env:UserProfile\Desktop\New Folder" -File -Fo).Name > file.csv`. Please note that your CSV will probably be encoded as UTF-16 with the little-endian byte order. If you want a different encoding type, UTF8  or ASCII for instance, do it like this instead, `Get-ChildItem -Path "$Env:UserProfile\Desktop\New Folder" -File -Force | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path ".\file.csv"`, or shortened `Ls "$Env:UserProfile\Desktop\New Folder" -File -Fo|Select -Exp Name|SC -En ASCII file.csv`

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
(dir "PATH" -file | select name) >file.csv
```

Basename only returns the file name of the item. To filter only files add the `-File` switch with `dir` and to get recursively add `-Recurse`. You can add other properties comma separated, too.

Comment: So this works but I need file extensions and don't need mode nor LastWriteTime.

Comment: Modified as per your need

Comment: Thank you but now I'm getting a blank CSV file? I used: `(dir "C:\Users\NAME.OFF\desktop\New Folder" -file | select name) > file.csv`

Comment: @adrift - confirm that your target dir has files in it. the code you show SHOULD work if there is at least one file in the target dir ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

A bit more idiomatic way to do this:

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -Property Name | Export-Csv "files.csv"
```

If you need to do get a list from another directory add -Path:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path
```

Answer (score -2):

My post is based on solution provided by @wasif in this same thread.

Removing the Brackets worked for me.

Try like this:

dir "PATH" -file | select name > file.csv